# Decrease voltage but keep same Amperage?

Tags: voltage

I have a controller which use 12V 3A. And I got old laptop power supply which is 19V 3A what resistor I need to include to decrease the voltage from 19V to 12V but keep the same 3A? Or I need to use any diode?

Here is the controller https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000012888935.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.67ca4c4dnQhqek

I have a Power supply at 12V 1A, but doesn't start properly. Seems it is weak as current. The most strange thing is that when I test it with multi meter shows not 12V but 16V.

Comment: Buy  a proper supply. Even a big 3A wall wart Stacking diodes to drop 19V to 12V is inefficient and clumsy. That's 20W of heat being produced so it will take a big heatsink and you will end up spending more money.

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and own findings in considerable detail with a schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Comment: LM317 connected as high current source using power transistor (one with high current rating or more with smaller). The schematic is in datasheet of LM317. Count with bigger heatsink due to power loss about 20W.

Answer (score 3):

This can't be done with a resistor. The voltage drop will change depending on the current.

It could *sort of* be done with diodes, but it will not work well and it will waste tons of power.

You either need a different power supply, or a SWITCHING REGULATOR, also known as a buck converter. These are available pre-assembled on a PCB:

[image: buck covnerter]

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000064597454.html

Check the buck converter voltage and current specs to make sure it can supply 12V at 3A.

It will have to be a switching regulator, NOT something linear like the LM7812, as that will get extremely hot due to the inefficiency.

Answer (score 0):

It will be more sane to get convert 19V 3A to 12V with more than 3A with a buck converter.

Resistors are not suitable for what you want.

It will be easiest to get a suitable 12V 3A power supply to begin with.

Since your original 12V power supply outputs 16V without load, i.e. a factor of 1.33 more, it means it's just an unregulated power supply. Or broken and gives overvoltage.